# Android App Crash after applied Proguard

Tags: android, proguard

My android app works very well in debug mode and when I generate the signed apk. When I applied Proguard I don't get any error. But when I installed the signed apk with proguard the app crash, I don't know what is the error because I only got "Unfortunately, my app has stopped".

Please give me a cable to know how can I detect what happens with my app, thanks

Comment: proguard does lots of optimizations, It also changes the class name, if you are using some class name statically then your application will crash. It would be great if you share crash log and progaurd file.

Comment: share your log cat

Comment: Sorry, how can I get the log cat, I can generate the apk signed with proguard without any problems. After I install the apk manually in a device, but when I try to use the app it crash. I dont know how can I get the logs after I install an app?